# Efficiency of Query to Select Records based on Related Records in Composite Table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

## Setup

I am creating an event listing where users can narrow down results by several filters. Rather than having a table for each filter (i.e. event_category, event_price) I have the following database structure (to make it easy/flexible to add more filters later):

**event**

```
event_id    title    description   [etc...]
-------------------------------------------
```

**fllter**

```
filter_id    name        slug
-----------------------------
1            Category    category
2            Price       price
```

**filter_item**

```
filter_item_id    filter_id   name          slug
------------------------------------------------
1                 1           Music         music
2                 1           Restaurant    restaurant
3                 2           High          high
4                 2           Low           low
```

**event_filter_item**

```
event_id    filter_item_id
--------------------------
1           1
1           4
2           1
2           3
```

## Goal

I want to query the database and apply the filters that users specify. For example, if a user searches for events in 'Music' (category) priced 'Low' (price) then only one event will show (with event_id = 1).

The URL would look something like:

```
www.site.com/events?category=music&price=low
```

So I need to query the database with the filter 'slugs' I receive from the URL.

This is the query I have written to make this work:

```
SELECT ev.* FROM event ev  
WHERE  
EXISTS (SELECT * FROM event_filter_item efi 
    JOIN filter_item fi on fi.filter_item_id = efi.filter_item_id
    JOIN filter f on f.filter_id = fi.filter_id 
    WHERE efi.event_id = ev.event_id AND f.slug = 'category' AND fi.slug ='music')
AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM event_filter_item efi 
    JOIN filter_item fi on fi.filter_item_id = efi.filter_item_id
    JOIN filter f on f.filter_id = fi.filter_id 
    WHERE efi.event_id = ev.event_id AND f.slug = 'price' AND fi.slug = 'low')
```

This query is currently hardcoded but would be dynamically generated in PHP based on what filters and slugs are present in the URL.

## And the big question...

Is this a reasonable way to go about this? Does anyone see a problem with having multiple EXISTS() with sub-queries, and those subqueries performing several joins? This query is extremely quick with only a couple records in the database, but what about when there are thousands or tens of thousands?

Any guidance is really appreciated!

Best,

Chris

Answer (score 0):

While EXISTS is just a form of JOIN, MySQL query optimizer is notoriously ["stupid"](http://solutionfactor.net/blog/2011/11/06/mysql-inner-join-vs-exists-may-yield-better-performance/) about executing it optimally. In your case, it will probably do a full table scan on the outer table, then execute the correlated subquery for each row, which is bound to scale badly. People often rewrite EXISTS as explicit JOIN for that reason. Or, just use a smarter DBMS.

In addition to that, consider using a composite PK for `filter_item`, where FK is at the leading edge - [InnoDB tables are clustered](http://www.ovaistariq.net/521/understanding-innodb-clustered-indexes/) and you'd want to group items belonging to the same filter physically close together.

BTW, tens of thousands is not a "large" number of rows - to truly test the scalability use tens of millions or more.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I didn't know that mysql whas *that* stupid... (the two versions are equivalent, as you probably know) BTW: does Innodb have approvements for this ?

Comment: @wildplasser I believe not.